# Почему вызов m(null) не считается неоднозначным?

Tags: java

```
public class H1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m(null);
    }       
    public static void m(Object o) {System.out.println("Object");}
    public static void m(String s) {System.out.println("String");}
    //public static void m(Integer i) {System.out.println("Integer");}
}
```

Данный код компилируется и выводит в консоль "String". Вопрос: почему вызов m(null) не считается неоднозначным, ведь если раскоментировать строку с параметром типа Integer неоднозначность появится.

Comment: Потому что String s = null  так же будет верно как и Object o = null. Так как тип null нельзя определить (собственно Object  или таки  String ) ввиду того что оба бывают null, то и возникает неоднозначность между `m(Object o)`  и `m(String s)`

Comment: @nick_n_a прочитайте внимательно вопрос. Если бы неоднозначность возникала, то вопроса не было бы. Неоднозначность как раз НЕ возникает.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что используется правило выбора наиболее подходящего метода (из спецификации - [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)).

В вашем примере для `null`-аргумента подходят два метода, но класс `Object` является родительским классом для `String`, поэтому компилятор останавливается на `void m(String s)`.

Если раскомментировать метод `void m(Integer i)`, то для компилятора оба метода (кроме `void m(Object o)`) будут наиболее подходящими - отсюда и сообщение об неоднозначности вызова метода.